# Apply JUnit 5 Extensions to specific package with tests

Tags: junit, junit5, junit-jupiter, junit5-extension-model

In my project, I have both API and UI tests, which are in different packages. I am using JUnit 5 as the test runner with some extensions for UI tests.

I have property `junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled=true` which means, that all extensions listed in *META-INF/services/org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.Extension* file will be applied to my `@Test` (both API and UI).

The problem is I want this extensions to be applied ONLY to UI tests (which are in separate package).

First solution that comes to mind is to create `BaseUiTest` class, `@ExtendWith` all extensions which I want to apply to UI tests only and then inherit my UI tests from that class.
OR
Create annotation `@UiTest`, apply extensions and use it instead of default `@Test`

I don't like both options, so maybe there is different approach to apply extensions for UI package only ?